# Fetch details from OData "location"

Tags: sapui5

I am using POST method to fetch some data from backend. 
In response, I can see "sap-message" as well as "location".

[image]

To use properties of "sap-message", I am simply using message model (message>code) in my frontend myView.view.XML, & it works well.

**My question is,** can I use string from "location" in my view file? For example, I want to use order number 1011520 along with code in my frontend.( e.g. code 1132 [1011520] ) Is there any way to fetch location string from batch call and use it?

Comment: do you get this in response of the oData call?

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi Yes, pic I shared is of my oData call

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "location" in frontend. Try implementing ABAP changes where you can order number in sap-message itself.

Using "location" is not preferred also by security point of view, because different systems will have different location URL.